# Call a function only once while serial data evaluates to a specific number

Tags: serial-port, logic, processing

So my logic is kind of butts. But here's what I'm going for: I have a stream of serial data and some booleans to track. What I really want to do is: "While serial data is equal to [X], call a specific function only once."

Basically: Get incoming serial data to act a bit like buttons. I always falter on where to set the flag back to false for the individual arguments. Right now I just have a total reset, if nothing is coming in, reset it all.

Any help on where to set the booleans back to false for the individual arguments would be appreciated. I mostly just can't see it.

Eventually this thing will do something along the lines of "while serial is 2, get a random point on the screen, and draw a circle" But for now, just solving my bad logic.

```java
import processing.serial.*;
Serial myPort;  // Create object from Serial class
int val;

boolean wasTwo = false;
boolean wasFour = false;
boolean wasSeven = false;


// /dev/cu.LightBlue-Bean
void setup() 
{
    size(800, 800);
    printArray(Serial.list());
    String portName = Serial.list()[1];// /dev/cu.LightBlue-Bean
    myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
}

void draw(){
    background(0);

    if ( myPort.available() > 0) {  // If data is available,
        val = myPort.read();         // read it and store it in val 
    }

    if(val != 0){

        if(!wasTwo && val == 2){
            print("2");
            wasTwo = true;
        } 

        if(!wasFour && val == 4){
            print("4");
            wasFour = true;
        } 

        if(!wasSeven && val == 7){
            print("7");
            wasSeven = true;
        }

    } else {
        wasTwo = false;
        wasFour = false;
        wasSeven = false;
    }


    if(wasTwo){
        red();
    }

    if(wasFour){
        green();
    }

    if(wasSeven){
        blue();
    }

}

void red(){
    fill(255,0,0);
    ellipse(200,200, 200, 200);

}

void green(){
    fill(0,200,0);
    ellipse(400,400, 200, 200);

}

void blue(){
    fill(0,0,255);
    ellipse(600,600, 200, 200);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of whether you've already seen the target value. You can do this with a `boolean` variable.

Then when you read the serial data, you check the value. If it's **not** the target value, then you simply set the `boolean` to false. If it **is** the target value, then you do another check: have you already seen the target value? If not, call your function and set the `boolean` to `true`. If so, then **don't** call the function.

Putting it all together, it might look like this:

```java
boolean sawTarget = false;
int targetValue = 2;

void draw(){

   if ( myPort.available() > 0) {
      int serialValue = myPort.read();

      if(serialValue == targetValue){
          if(!sawTarget){
              doSomething();
          }
          sawTarget = true;
      }
      else{
          sawTarget = false;
      }
   }
}
```

Also note that this assumes the timing of your serial events is correct. Note that it's possible for your serial events to fire faster than 60 times per second, in which case you'd have a build-up of unprocessed events. In that case you might want to use a `while()` loop instead of your outermost `if` statement, or use the `serialEvent()` function instead.